# MySQL - Difference between values related to a date

Tags: mysql

With help of the following query I'm able to request the difference between two values for a specific ID between two dates.

```
SET @ID = 46;
SET @DATE1 = '2017-02-08';
SET @DATE2 = '2017-02-12';


select today.value - tbd_date.value from
(Select value from Table1 WHERE Datum = @DATE1 and ID = @ID) as today
CROSS JOIN
( (Select value from Table1 WHERE Datum = @DATE2 and ID = @ID) as tbd_date)
```

But there are more than one ID. How is the query to get for all IDs of the Table the difference between this two dates?

Afterwards I want to sort them based on the difference of the values.

Table:

```
ID        DATE           value
46        2017-02-08     5
47        2017-02-08     8
48        2017-02-08     10
46        2017-02-12     7
47        2017-02-12     11
48        2017-02-12     5
```

Result:

```
ID        value (today)  difference
47        11             +3
46        7              +2
48        5              -5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join on the id:

```
Select a.id, b.value - a.value
From table1 a
   join table1 b on b.Id = a.Id 
      and b.datum = @date2
      and a.datum = @date1
order by b.value - a.value
```